# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,10) into shape (10,18)

Tags: python, numpy

Im using python 3.5 and am attempting a broadcast a 2d list into a 3d list.

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,10) into shape (10,18)
```

Here is the code I am using that generates the error

```
v_level =4
M=16
n_down = M/2
n_down0 = M
residual_h_to_2h = np.zeros((v_level,M+2,M+2))
residual_h_to_2h[q][0:n_down+2][0:n_down+2] = restrict(residual_h[0:n_down0+2][0:n_down0+2])
```

The shape (0,18) corresponds to residual_h_to_2h. The function restrict returns a list of shape ( (M/2)+2 , (N/2)+2) where (M,N) is the shape of input list.

I am not able to understand why the shape of residual_h_to_2h[q][0:n_down+2][0:n_down+2] is reported as 10,18. It should be 10,10.

I do not seem to be able to resolve this issue on my own. Any help or links to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to print the values of your variables ?

Comment: 16+2 = 18 and 16/2 + 2 = 10. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: Can't you get rid of all those `+2` expressions?  It makes harder to read. And probably makes it harder for you to track the shape of the arrays.

Comment: @muraveill yes I did. LHS is a full 4x18x18 list,whereas the RHS isa 10x10

Comment: @hruske true. But the LHS is only 16/2 +2 twice

Comment: @hpaulj True. it makes harder. But creating another set of variables will make it even more complicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ooh, now I see it.

Correct slicing with three dimensions:

```
residual_h_to_2h[q,0:n_down+2,0:n_down+2].shape
(10, 10)
```

---

**Why?**

You are slicing by the same dimension both times you're using `0:ndown+2`. Original ndarray:

```
residual_h_to_2h.shape
(4, 18, 18)
```

First level is scalar and it reduces dimension:

```
residual_h_to_2h[q].shape
(18, 18)
```

Second level is slicing and it does not reduce dimension so these are actually equal and same:

```
residual_h_to_2h[q][0:n_down+2][0:n_down+2].shape
(10, 18)

residual_h_to_2h[q][0:n_down+2].shape
(10, 18)
```

It gets easier to spot if having not `a` times `a`, but `a` times `b` array:

```
residual_h_to_2h[q][0:10].shape
(10, 18)

residual_h_to_2h[q][0:10][0:5].shape
(5, 18)
```